# How to add dynamic row Item in activity and able to access its ids?

Tags: android, dynamic, row

My requirement is: After click on + icon , a new row should add dynamically and able to access its ids. Please give suggestions to implement it.

[image]

Comment: Please tell us what have you done so far. Add some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to display the items in a ListView/RecyclerView and simply add the new item into adapter and let the adapter handle adding the new row Item. You don't have to care about the items id and can simply use the adapters position as an id.

When you create a view programmatically, you can assign the View id by calling View.setID(), which can be any int (it must be unique). I wouldn't recommend this approach because it'll get very tedious to track the id's and the data the items contains. Using RecyclerView/ListView elevates this problem by separating the data from the presentation layers.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to add new row dynamically, but not able to create new ids

```
public void onAddField(View v) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field, null);
        // Add the new row before the add field button.
        parentLinearLayout.addView(rowView, parentLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 6);
    }
```

in field.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >    
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/grid_Itemcode"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"       
        android:inputType="textPhonetic"
        android:hint="Code" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/grid_itemdesc"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"        
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Description" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/grid_itemQty"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"        
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:hint="Qty" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/grid_itemRate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"        
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:hint="Rate" />
<Button
        android:id="@+id/delete_button" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        android:onClick="onDelete"/>
</LinearLayout>
```